# Javascript showing wrong results

Tags: javascript

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="score-board.css">
<title>Score Board App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="playersscores">
<span id="p1score">0</span><span> To </span> <span id="p2score">0</span>
</div>
<p>Playing to <span id="score">5</span></p>

<input type="field" value="5" ></input>
<button id="p1clicked">Player one</button>
<button id="p2clicked">Player two</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="score-board.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript is :

Whenever this code is loaded :

```
var p1result = document.querySelector("#p1score");
var p2result = document.querySelector("#p2score");
var p1clicked = document.querySelector("#p1clicked");

function increment_score (player_result) {
    //var score = parseInt(player_result.innerText) + 1;
    player_result.innerText = (parseInt(player_result.innerText) + 1).toString();
}


p1clicked.addEventListener("onclick", increment_score(p1result))
```

Whenever this code is loaded in a browser, the span showing the result for player 1 is showing one directly without clicking on player 1 button. i'm not sure what is wrong with the event listener im using.

Answer (score 1):

1. The event is `click` instead of `onclick`
2. The event listener should be a reference to the function itself, not the result of a function call (which increments the score by 1)
3. Inside the function, you can access the button with `this`:

The code could look like this:

```
function increment_score() {
    var player_result = this;
    player_result.innerText = (parseInt(player_result.innerText) + 1).toString();
}

p1clicked.addEventListener('click', increment_score);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/click) event not `onclick`
2. You pass result of function not instead reference to function
3. If you need pass parameters to event handler - you can use bind:

---

```
p1clicked.addEventListener("click", increment_score.bind({result: p1result, inc: 1  }) )
p2clicked.addEventListener("click", increment_score.bind({result: p2result, inc: 2  }) )

function increment_score () {
    var score = parseInt(this.result.innerText) + this.inc;
    this.result.innerText = score;
}
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/6vw8ay3x/ ]

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple problems there.  First, when calling the addEventListener function, you need to specify just "click", not "onclick".  Secondly, when you pass the function to addEventListener, you just want it to be a reference to the function not an actual function call.  The following changes will net you the result you are seeking.

```
function increment_score () {
  p1result.innerText = (parseInt(p1result.innerText) + 1).toString();
}

p1clicked.addEventListener("click", increment_score);
```

But since you want to be able to use the same function for multiple players, then I would suggest adding the "onclick" handler to the HTML which will allow you to pass the element you want to increment.  Then your HTML code would look like this:

```
<button id="p1clicked" onclick="increment_score_with_param(p1result);">Player one</button>
<button id="p2clicked" onclick="increment_score_with_param(p2result);">Player two</button>
```

and your javascript would be:

```
var p1result = document.querySelector("#p1score");
var p2result = document.querySelector("#p2score");
var p1clicked = document.querySelector("#p1clicked");

function increment_score_with_param (player_result) {
  player_result.innerText = (parseInt(player_result.innerText) + 1).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var p1result = document.querySelector('#p1score');
    var p2result = document.querySelector('#p2score');
    var p1clicked = document.querySelector('#p1clicked');
    p1clicked.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        p1result.innerText = (parseInt(p1result.innerText) + 1).toString();
    });
}
```